# How do you make the Recyclerview and Cardview transparent

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a recyclerview that I would like to share the same background as the activity so that only the textviews inside the recyclerview are visible. I've tried things like this in the cardview and recyclerview xmls:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

and

```
android:background="@null"
```

They haven't worked. Is this possible? I haven't found any answers in previously asked questions on here that have been successful. Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Cardview is for beautifying layout and giving shadow to it, If you don't want to use this feature than you should avoid CardView and use simple `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `ConstraintLayout` etc. and than give transparent background to it.

But still you want to use CardView, remove this line

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

and add this line to your CardView.

```
 app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fragment, you need to add it on your container instead of replacing it:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(YourFragment(),"tag").commit()
```